# How to get Instagram data from a user on Android?

Tags: android, json, getjson, instagram

I'm trying to fetch user data from Instagram in a Android application, because I need to get user photos and show in a gallery, but I'm having a problem to fetch user data.

Here is the code:

```
private void fetchUserName() {
    mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching user info");
            int what = WHAT_FINALIZE;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/users/" + mSession.getId() + "/media/recent/?access_token=" + mAccessToken);

                Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("full_name");
                String bio = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("bio");
                Log.i(TAG, "Got name: " + name + ", bio [" + bio + "]");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                what = WHAT_ERROR;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();  

}
```

But in this part is going to catch.

```
 String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

And I tried many ways to do JSON parse, but always give error when try to connect to url, like it:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The url logged is :

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/699022341/?access_token=699022341.aef690f.1888e66fed5d4764aeae1c121faa14fb

And the error is:

```
11-29 14:31:45.300: W/System.err(11916): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/699022341/?access_token=699022341.aef690f.1888e66fed5d4764aeae1c121faa14fb
11-29 14:31:45.300: W/System.err(11916):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
11-29 14:31:45.300: W/System.err(11916):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
```

I'm doing something wrong or need a Instagram permission, or something like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the below code for Instagram user authentication process, here is share my code. Hope it will help to you,

**InstagramApp.java**

```
package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.InstagramDialog.OAuthDialogListener;

/**
 * 
 * @author Thiago Locatelli <thiago.locatelli@gmail.com>
 * @author Lorensius W. L T <lorenz@londatiga.net>
 * 
 */
public class InstagramApp {

    private InstagramSession mSession;
    private InstagramDialog mDialog;
    private OAuthAuthenticationListener mListener;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private String mAuthUrl;
    private String mTokenUrl;
    private String mAccessToken;
    private Context mCtx;

    private String mClientId;
    private String mClientSecret;

    private static int WHAT_FINALIZE = 0;
    private static int WHAT_ERROR = 1;
    private static int WHAT_FETCH_INFO = 2;

    /**
     * Callback url, as set in 'Manage OAuth Costumers' page
     * (https://developer.github.com/)
     */

    public static String mCallbackUrl = "";
    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
    private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";

    private static final String TAG = "InstagramAPI";

    public InstagramApp(Context context, String clientId, String clientSecret,
            String callbackUrl) {

        mClientId = clientId;
        mClientSecret = clientSecret;
        mCtx = context;
        mSession = new InstagramSession(context);
        mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();
        mCallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
        mTokenUrl = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret="
                + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + mCallbackUrl
                + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
        mAuthUrl = AUTH_URL
                + "?client_id="
                + clientId
                + "&redirect_uri="
                + mCallbackUrl
                + "&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=likes+comments+relationships";

        OAuthDialogListener listener = new OAuthDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String code) {
                getAccessToken(code);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                mListener.onFail("Authorization failed");
            }
        };

        mDialog = new InstagramDialog(context, mAuthUrl, listener);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    }

    private void getAccessToken(final String code) {
        mProgress.setMessage("Getting access token ...");
        mProgress.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Getting access token");
                int what = WHAT_FETCH_INFO;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(TOKEN_URL);
                    // URL url = new URL(mTokenUrl + "&code=" + code);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Opening Token URL " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    // urlConnection.connect();
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write("client_id=" + mClientId + "&client_secret="
                            + mClientSecret + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                            + "&redirect_uri=" + mCallbackUrl + "&code=" + code);
                    writer.flush();
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection
                            .getInputStream());
                    Log.i(TAG, "response " + response);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                            .nextValue();

                    mAccessToken = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Got access token: " + mAccessToken);

                    String id = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                    String user = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString(
                            "username");
                    String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString(
                            "full_name");
                    String userImage = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString(
                            "profile_picture");
                    mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, id, user, name,
                            userImage);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    what = WHAT_ERROR;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void fetchUserName() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fetching user info");
                int what = WHAT_FINALIZE;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/users/" + mSession.getId()
                            + "/?access_token=" + mAccessToken);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection
                            .getInputStream());
                    System.out.println(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                            .nextValue();
                    String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString(
                            "full_name");
                    // String bio =
                    // jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("bio");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got name: " + name);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    what = WHAT_ERROR;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
            }
        }.start();

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == WHAT_ERROR) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                if (msg.arg1 == 1) {
                    mListener.onFail("Failed to get access token");
                } else if (msg.arg1 == 2) {
                    mListener.onFail("Failed to get user information");
                }
            } else if (msg.what == WHAT_FETCH_INFO) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                mListener.onSuccess();
                // fetchUserName();
            } else {
                // mProgress.dismiss();
                // mListener.onSuccess();
            }
        }
    };

    public boolean hasAccessToken() {
        return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
    }

    public void setListener(OAuthAuthenticationListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    // getting username
    public String getUserName() {
        return mSession.getUsername();
    }

    // getting user id
    public String getId() {
        return mSession.getId();
    }

    // getting username
    public String getName() {
        return mSession.getName();
    }

    // getting user image
    public String getUserPicture() {
        return mSession.getUserImage();
    }

    // getting accesstoken
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return mSession.getAccessToken();
    }

    public void authorize() {
        // Intent webAuthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // webAuthIntent.setData(Uri.parse(AUTH_URL));
        // mCtx.startActivity(webAuthIntent);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String str = "";

        if (is != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }

            str = sb.toString();
        }

        return str;
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mSession.resetAccessToken();
            mAccessToken = null;
        }
    }

    public interface OAuthAuthenticationListener {
        public abstract void onSuccess();

        public abstract void onFail(String error);
    }
}
```

**InstagramDialog.java**

```
package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Display 37Signals authentication dialog.
 * 
 * @author Thiago Locatelli <thiago.locatelli@gmail.com>
 * @author Lorensius W. L T <lorenz@londatiga.net>
 * 
 */
public class InstagramDialog extends Dialog {

    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = { 460, 260 };
    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = { 420, 420 };
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    static final int MARGIN = 4;
    static final int PADDING = 2;

    private String mUrl;
    private OAuthDialogListener mListener;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mContent;
    private TextView mTitle;

    private static final String TAG = "Instagram-WebView";

    public InstagramDialog(Context context, String url,
            OAuthDialogListener listener) {
        super(context);

        mUrl = url;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");
        mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setUpTitle();
        setUpWebView();

        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float[] dimensions = (display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()) ? DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT
                : DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE;

        addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f), (int) (dimensions[1]
                        * scale + 0.5f)));
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    }

    private void setUpTitle() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mTitle = new TextView(getContext());
        mTitle.setText("Instagram");
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        mContent.addView(mTitle);
    }

    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }

    private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);

            if (url.startsWith(InstagramApp.mCallbackUrl)) {
                String urls[] = url.split("=");
                mListener.onComplete(urls[1]);
                InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Page error: " + description);

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            mListener.onError(description);
            InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished URL: " + url);
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public interface OAuthDialogListener {
        public abstract void onComplete(String accessToken);

        public abstract void onError(String error);
    }

}
```

**InstagramSession.java**

```
package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

/**
 * Manage access token and user name. Uses shared preferences to store access
 * token and user name.
 * 
 * @author Thiago Locatelli <thiago.locatelli@gmail.com>
 * @author Lorensius W. L T <lorenz@londatiga.net>
 * 
 */
public class InstagramSession {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private Editor editor;

    private static final String SHARED = "Instagram_Preferences";
    private static final String API_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String API_ID = "id";
    private static final String API_NAME = "name";
    private static final String API_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
    private static final String API_USER_IMAGE = "user_image";

    public InstagramSession(Context context) {
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param accessToken
     * @param expireToken
     * @param expiresIn
     * @param username
     */
    public void storeAccessToken(String accessToken, String id,
            String username, String name, String image) {
        editor.putString(API_ID, id);
        editor.putString(API_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
        editor.putString(API_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(API_USER_IMAGE, image);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void storeAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        editor.putString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Reset access token and user name
     */
    public void resetAccessToken() {
        editor.putString(API_ID, null);
        editor.putString(API_NAME, null);
        editor.putString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
        editor.putString(API_USERNAME, null);
        editor.putString(API_USER_IMAGE, null);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Get user name
     * 
     * @return User name
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return sharedPref.getString(API_USERNAME, null);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getId() {
        return sharedPref.getString(API_ID, null);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getName() {
        return sharedPref.getString(API_NAME, null);
    }

    /**
     * Get access token
     * 
     * @return Access token
     */
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return sharedPref.getString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
    }

    /**
     * Get userImage
     * 
     * @return userImage
     */
    public String getUserImage() {
        return sharedPref.getString(API_USER_IMAGE, null);
    }
}
```

The above three classes are static one and i say my thanks to the author, in InstagramApp.java class i little bit modified the getter setter methods to get all user values, and in MainActivity.java i used the below code.

```
  private InstagramApp instaObj;
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "Your_ID";
    public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "Your_Sec_Key";
    public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "Your_call_back_URL";

        // Instagram Implementation

            instaObj = new InstagramApp(this, CLIENT_ID,
                    CLIENT_SECRET, CALLBACK_URL);
            instaObj.setListener(listener);


            instaObj.authorize();  //add this in your button click or wherever you need to call the instagram api



                        OAuthAuthenticationListener listener = new OAuthAuthenticationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                Log.e("Userid", instaObj.getId());
                Log.e("Name", instaObj.getName());
                Log.e("UserName", instaObj.getUserName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(String error) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: @Daniel Nazareth: is my answer is helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks man, it was useful to correct some errors! The error that was in fetchUserName() class was my bigger trouble, solve it commenting the urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); line

Comment: @DanielNazareth: Nice, happy coding.. :)

Comment: Once you authorize the user and while getting the access token its giving me an error @Aerrow

Comment: @Hummer: Could you plz post the exact error, which you faced

Comment: InstagramApp$1.handleMessage(InstagramApp.java:186)
and this is pointing to mListener.onSuccess(); in Handler()

Comment: Is it safe to store the client & secret key in the code? Just wondering what happens if someone decompiles the apk an accesses the keys. I'd like to know if this is the best practice.

Comment: Hey, I am using this code but problem is when i call it first time it showing me blank white screen. Can you help me how can i avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Your **InstagramApp.java**

Just replace it with your current class in library.

```
package br.com.dina.oauth.instagram;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.InstagramDialog.OAuthDialogListener;

/**
 * 
 * @author Thiago Locatelli <thiago.locatelli@gmail.com>
 * @author Lorensius W. L T <lorenz@londatiga.net>
 * 
 */
public class InstagramApp {

    private InstagramSession mSession;
    private InstagramDialog mDialog;
    private OAuthAuthenticationListener mListener;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private String mAuthUrl;
    private String mTokenUrl;
    private String mAccessToken;
    private Context mCtx;

    private String mClientId;
    private String mClientSecret;


    private static int WHAT_FINALIZE = 0;
    private static int WHAT_ERROR = 1;
    private static int WHAT_FETCH_INFO = 2;

    /**
     * Callback url, as set in 'Manage OAuth Costumers' page
     * (https://developer.github.com/)
     */

    public static String mCallbackUrl = "";
    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
    private static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";

    private static final String TAG = "InstagramAPI";

    public InstagramApp(Context context, String clientId, String clientSecret,
            String callbackUrl) {

        mClientId = clientId;
        mClientSecret = clientSecret;
        mCtx = context;
        mSession = new InstagramSession(context);
        mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();
        mCallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
        mTokenUrl = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret="
                + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + mCallbackUrl + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
        mAuthUrl = AUTH_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri="
                + mCallbackUrl + "&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=likes+comments+relationships";

        OAuthDialogListener listener = new OAuthDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String code) {
                getAccessToken(code);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                mListener.onFail("Authorization failed");
            }
        };

        mDialog = new InstagramDialog(context, mAuthUrl, listener);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    }

    private void getAccessToken(final String code) {
        mProgress.setMessage("Getting access token ...");
        mProgress.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Getting access token");
                int what = WHAT_FETCH_INFO;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(TOKEN_URL);
                    //URL url = new URL(mTokenUrl + "&code=" + code);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Opening Token URL " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    //urlConnection.connect();
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write("client_id="+mClientId+
                                "&client_secret="+mClientSecret+
                                "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
                                "&redirect_uri="+mCallbackUrl+
                                "&code=" + code);
                    writer.flush();
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Log.i(TAG, "response " + response);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

                    mAccessToken = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got access token: " + mAccessToken);

                    String id = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                    String user = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                    String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("full_name");                 

                    mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, id, user, name);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    what = WHAT_ERROR;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void fetchUserName() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fetching user info");
                int what = WHAT_FINALIZE;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/users/" + mSession.getId() + "/?access_token=" + mAccessToken);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("full_name");
                    String bio = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("bio");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got name: " + name + ", bio [" + bio + "]");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    what = WHAT_ERROR;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
            }
        }.start();  

    }


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == WHAT_ERROR) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                if(msg.arg1 == 1) {
                    mListener.onFail("Failed to get access token");
                }
                else if(msg.arg1 == 2) {
                    mListener.onFail("Failed to get user information");
                }
            } 
            else if(msg.what == WHAT_FETCH_INFO) {
                fetchUserName();
            }
            else {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                mListener.onSuccess();
            }
        }
    };

    public boolean hasAccessToken() {
        return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
    }

    public void setListener(OAuthAuthenticationListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return mSession.getUsername();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mSession.getId();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mSession.getName();
    }

    public void authorize() {
        //Intent webAuthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        //webAuthIntent.setData(Uri.parse(AUTH_URL));
        //mCtx.startActivity(webAuthIntent);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String str = "";

        if (is != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }

            str = sb.toString();
        }

        return str;
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mSession.resetAccessToken();
            mAccessToken = null;
        }
    }

    public interface OAuthAuthenticationListener {
        public abstract void onSuccess();

        public abstract void onFail(String error);
    }
}
```